# PHP Replace multiple string within foreach loop

Tags: php, string, replace

I'm grabbing the source of a page with a lot of PDF links (files) listed in a column like so. simple_php_dom.php

```
TALB20170826D-$A$$-RA11.pdf
TAP$20170826D-$A$$-RA11.pdf
TASD20170826D-$A$$-RA11.pdf
TAUA20170826D-$A$$-RA11.pdf
TAUB20170826D-$A$$-RA11.pdf
TAUC20170826D-$A$$-RA11.pdf
TAUD20170826D-$A$$-RA11.pdf
TBTP20170826D-$A$$-RA11.pdf
TCBY20170826D-$A$$-RA11.pdf
```

I need to rename them within the foreach loop

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
echo $element->href;
```

For instance TALB is an abbreviation for ALBANY, TAP is an abbreviation for Asia Pacific and so on.

I have a list of the names that correspond with the abbreviations but unsure how to rename them within the loop? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the list of replacements in arrays:

```
<?php    
/*
$list = [];   
$list[] = "TALB20170826D-\$A$$-RA11.pdf";
$list[] = "TAP$20170826D-\$A$$-RA11.pdf";
$list[] = "TASD20170826D-\$A$$-RA11.pdf";
$list[] = "TAUA20170826D-\$A$$-RA11.pdf";
$list[] = "TAUB20170826D-\$A$$-RA11.pdf";
$list[] = "TAUC20170826D-\$A$$-RA11.pdf";
$list[] = "TAUD20170826D-\$A$$-RA11.pdf";
$list[] = "TBTP20170826D-\$A$$-RA11.pdf";
$list[] = "TCBY20170826D-\$A$$-RA11.pdf";
*/
$list = $html->find('a');
$abbr = [
    "TALB",
    "TAP",
    // ...
];
$replacements = [
    "ALBANY",
    "Asia Pacific",
    // ...
];
foreach ($list as &$el) {
    $el->href = str_replace($abbr, $replacements, $el->href);
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Tr2j0)

Or, to keep them all in one associative array (order doesn't matter and missing items just won't be replaced, no errors):

```
<?php    
/*$list = [];   
$list[] = "TALB20170826D-\$A$$-RA11.pdf";
$list[] = "TAP$20170826D-\$A$$-RA11.pdf";
$list[] = "TASD20170826D-\$A$$-RA11.pdf";
$list[] = "TAUA20170826D-\$A$$-RA11.pdf";
$list[] = "TAUB20170826D-\$A$$-RA11.pdf";
$list[] = "TAUC20170826D-\$A$$-RA11.pdf";
$list[] = "TAUD20170826D-\$A$$-RA11.pdf";
$list[] = "TBTP20170826D-\$A$$-RA11.pdf";
$list[] = "TCBY20170826D-\$A$$-RA11.pdf";*/
$list = $html->find('a');
$abbr = [
    "TALB" => "ALBANY",
    "TAP" => "Asia Pacific",
];
foreach ($list as &$el) {
    $el->href = strtr($el->href, $abbr);
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/be0k1)

Or use `array_map()`, maybe you'll find it a bit cleaner:

```
$list = array_map(function($el) use($abbr) {
    return strtr($el, $abbr);
}, $list);
```

Comment: Will this work if the abbreviations aren't in order or sometimes not listed?

Comment: It won't with the first way, but I edited in another way of doing it which will do it the way you want it to.

Comment: That works! Now how would I get the pdf link names into the $list = [] array?
For instance, the date within the string will change everyday I grab the links.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Where are you getting the list from? You should post a new question though, to keep things organized.

Comment: I've edited, now the $list comes directly from `$html->find('a')`.